# What is the minimum number that must share the same birthday (month & day) each year, given that one such birthday is February 29?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

If there are 6,392 students at Stack Exchange College.  What is the minimum number that must share the same birthday (month & day) each year, given that one such birthday is February 29?

Comment: Are you asking for the minimum of the maximum number of people sharing a birthday?

Comment: use Pigeonhole Principle or Dirichlet Box Principle!

Comment: Can you solve a smaller problem of the same type? If there are 10 people and 3 neighborhoods, what is the minimum number that must come from the same neighborhood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I'm not entirely sure i'm answering your question correctly but just compute 6392/366 and round down to 17. Unless you are asking for the expected value in which case this is incorrect.